# What why doesn't the super() constructor take the same arguments as the parent constructor?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-recyclerview, constructor

I'm implementing custom recyclerviews to respond to instances of a class that with certain parameters. To do this I had implement VieHolders. I created an abstract ViewHolder so I can pass both layouts to be inflated. However, when I inherit from the superclass and try to implement the constructor on the abstract class it doesn't take the arguments that the concrete class would and I get an error saying no default constructor is available from the parent class.

What I'm expecting to work:

```
 private abstract class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
      public CrimeHolder(View view, ViewGroup parent, Boolean false){
           super(view, parent, false);
      }
```

And then the classes that extend from that would just do this:

```
 private class RegularCrimeHolder extends CrimeHolder{
      public RegularCrimeHolder(Inflater inflater, ViewGroup parent{
           super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false));
      }
 }
```

But what is actually happening is that CrimeHolder can't pass the same arguments to the superconstructor as a concrete class or I get a "There is no default constructor found" so CrimeHolder gets written like this:

```
abstract class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CrimeHolder(View view){
        super(view);
    }


}
```

Despite the fact that that the constructor I had to write for CrimeHolder only takes one View argument I still have to pass the full arguments to the superconstructor in RegularCrimeHolder. Why is the child class calling a super constructor with so many arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm expecting to work

The constructor for `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` [takes a single `View` parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#RecyclerView.ViewHolder(android.view.View)). You are attempting to pass three parameters. That will not compile.

> And then the classes that extend from that would just do this

Your `CrimeViewHolder` constructor takes three parameters. Your `RegularCrimeHolder` subclass is attempting to pass a single parameter. That will not compile.

> Despite the fact that that the constructor I had to write for CrimeHolder only takes one View argument

No, the `super` call takes one parameter. Your constructor that you declared takes three parameters.

> Why is the child class calling a super constructor with so many arguments?

Presumably, you typed that in. It looks like you tried mimicking the parameter list for an `inflate()` call on a `LayoutInflater`.

Rewrite your `CrimeHolder` as:

```
private abstract class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
  public CrimeHolder(View view){
       super(view);
  }
```

Rewrite your `RegularCrimeHolder` as:

```
private class RegularCrimeHolder extends CrimeHolder{
      public RegularCrimeHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
           super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false));
      }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake. What was being passed was the return value of inflate() so it was just one parameter.